# Bind params to a model without indicating model's name?

Tags: forms, data-binding, playframework

Using Play Framework, you can do something like this:

```
public static void mymethod() {
    // do stuff here
    MyModel mymodel = new MyModel();
    Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "mymodel", mymodel);

    // equivalent to specifying this in the method params :
    // mymethod (@Valid MyModel mymodel)
}
```

But that would require that you send your params as "mymodel.name", "mymodel.title", etc (with name & title in the model).

What I'd like to do is getting rid of the "mymodel." in the params, just sending "name", "title", and bind them directly to my model.

I know I can't do that with `@Valid` (well, as far as I know), but I tried something like this, and it didn't work :

```
Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "", mymodel); // Nothing between quotes
```

I know this is possible, I found it before but can't put my finger on it now, could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll answer myself on that one.

All you have to do is replace this :

```
Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "mymodel", mymodel)
```

by this :

```
Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), mymodel, null);
```